# Cannot Transfer Facebook Graph API Variable to another Variable

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

```
if ($session)
{
//fb query
    try
    {
        $me = $facebook->api('/me');
    }
    catch (FacebookApiException $e)
    {
        echo $e->getMessasge();
    }
}

if($me){
$logoutUrl = $facebook->getLogoutUrl();
echo "<a href='$logoutUrl'>Logout</a>";
}
else{
$loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl($params);
echo "<a href='$loginUrl'>Login</a>";
}

echo $me['first_name'];

$me['first_name'] = $test;

echo $test;
```

I am trying to set Facebook Graph API variables to other variables (particularly session variables). I tried Session variables but it didn't work so I took a step back. In this example, it prints out `$me['first_name']` but not `$test`. Am I missing something simple here? I can't seem to transfer the value over. Eventually I'd like to take the value and enter it into a MySQL row but I can't get it to work on a simple variable.

I've got all the setup correct before this bit of code because it does display the variable correctly on the `$me['first_name']` but not on $test.

Thanks for the help and I apologize if it's a super basic problem that I'm just overlooking.

Comment: Where do you set $test? Or do you mean `$test = $me['first_name']` (i.e. you have the assignment the wrong way round?)

Comment: Oh man, I have been working for like two straight days and obviously need a little sleep. Thanks!

Comment: No problem. Added as an aswer to stop others working on it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Where do you set $test?

Or do you mean `$test = $me['first_name'];` (i.e. you have the assignment the wrong way round?)